# Cannot connect to Jupyter Notebook server in Azure HDInsight

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight, jupyter

I am trying to run a Python module using a Jupyter Notebook on Azure HDInsight, but I continue to get the following error message: *A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect, but until it does, you will NOT be able to run code. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration.*

I have an Azure subscription, created a cluster, created a storage blob, and have created a Jupyter Notebook. I am successfully logged into the cluster, so I am not sure why I cannot connect to the notebook. Any insight into this problem would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you have installed Jupyter Notebook on an Azure VM? Can you check if the desired endpoint is configured on the VM? By default, only a remote desktop and a PowerShell endpoint (for Windows), or an SSH endpoint (for Linux) is configured. If Jupyter uses another port, such as 80, it’s needed to manually configure the endpoint. Please check https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/?rnd=1 for more information. Feel free to let us know if we have any misunderstood on your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this question way too late, but I will venture that you are using an unsupported browser.

Please use Chrome to connect to Jupyter.